# SQLite - How to read a script file with one command line

Tags: sqlite, command-line-interface

I would like to launch a script from command line.

Usually I use the following for executing a sql query, eg:

```
cmd /c mydb.db "select count(*) from myTable;"
```

Here I have a file script.file, eg:

```
.open mydb.db
.mode csv
.import filePath.csv
.open mydb2.db
attach mydb.db;
etc...
```

I can launch it by doing, fine

```
cmd /c sqlite3
.read script.file
.exit
```

However I would like to do it with one command, eg:

```
cmd /c sqlite3 .read script.file
```

got an error and same with

```
cmd /c sqlite3 foo ".read script.file"
```

Any help? Thank you

Comment: Does the windows shell do redirection like unix ones? `cmd /c sqlite3 foo < script.file` might work if it does.

Comment: Hi, not working but the following rises : input is not a tty

Comment: This `cmd /c sqlite3 foo ".read script.file"` should be the correct syntax.

Comment: Correct. Working. I missed something when I tried the first time. Thank you!!